# How to expose a wcf service on IIS from specific port

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I have a wcf service application. When I try to browse it from vs2010 it works nicely. I specified address of the wcf as:

```
[http://localhost:2002/Service.svc]
```

Now I want to host this service on IIS. I searched on the internet but all I could find is, I must host it as:

```
[http://localhost/Service.svc]
```

But, I want to host it from the different port, just like web services. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the application bindings you can change the port. As long as that port is open in the firewall then you will be able to connect.

For example if you change the port in the image to 2002 and that port was open on the firewall you would be able to go to [http://ashleymedway.com:2002]

[image: IIS Binding]

Comment: if I do so I only get blank page. When I wrote (http://localhost:2002/Service.svc) I only get blank page

Comment: have you changed the binding correctly?

Comment: yes,i did. I cahnged port to 2002. And my endpoint adress is also 2002. But I only have blank page